# Overlapping data points and spacing

Tags: matlab, space, points

I have a set of data that I plot but the points on the graphs are so closed to each other that you can't see them well nd neither their values because even when I zoom in I can't get to them all. Now what I want to do is to space them out without changing their actual values on the graph. Is the a function or any other ways to do that? I've tried changing the axis and the scale but it didn't help. Mostly those points are in the Y direction. Please help What I really mean is though these points are closed to each other I'd like to create and interval between them so they don't pile up on each other

Comment: Post your code you used to scale the axis

Comment: @ Freude That is already done.  The data points I'm plotting are just what I want for my plot and I need all of them because I'm comparing it with a different one to see if the data changed over time. In other words I need all points

Comment: @ Dan I used axis([ xmin Xmas  ymin ymac]) I also tried Ytick but thr was doing what I really needed.

Comment: try `axis([xmin xmax ymin ymin + d])` where `d` is small compared to your data range. It sounds like you have too much data to view all at once. Also maybe add some code to your question like how you are plotting for example.

Comment: @user2299595: how about adding some random jitter to separate the  points apart?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the vector you are trying to plot to be more sparse taking points after some defined intervals:

```
plot(x(1:10:end),y(1:10:end))
```

In this example, I plotted each tenth point. Does it help?